# Python request get data through HTTPS tunnel

Tags: python, https, request, urllib2, tunnel

I am currently pulling data from a public series data from https://www3.bcb.gov.br/expectativas/publico/en/serieestatisticas

This is a public page that uses apache wicket I believe.

I usually am ok with scraping, whether GET or POST.  Here I and my colleagues are stuck.  Can anyone help understand what URL needs to be used to actually make the request.  Here's what I've got so far:

The form with inputs:
[image]

The Fiddler capture manually executed:
[image]

Text View:
form19_hf_0=&indicador=0&calculo=0&linhaPeriodicidade%3Aperiodicidade=0&tfDataInicial=11%2F10%2F2015&tfDataFinal=11%2F24%2F2015&divPeriodoRefereEstatisticas%3AgrupoAnoReferencia%3AanoReferenciaInicial=16&divPeriodoRefereEstatisticas%3AgrupoAnoReferencia%3AanoReferenciaFinal=16&btnCSV=Generate+CSV

Form data I'm passing in the request:
[image]

Summary:

I need some help, I can't seem to get the POST working correctly, it takes me to a different page, and I'm not sure of how to work through this one.

NB: I'm trying to grab back a CSV.

The libraries I'm using are primarily Requests (I was going to use LXML but I don't think its going to be applicable here).

I've been trying to figure out the right form with Postman and Fiddler to understand what the request needs to be.

Comment: Which URL do you post to, which HTTP status code do you get when being redirected? Which framework are you using for scraping? From personal experience, I can recommend [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for handling more complicated HTTP scenarios.

Comment: I'm using requests and lxml.  The confusion is i'm not sure of which one to use.  if it were simply getting back HTML and parsing that its fine, but its not just sending a post request.  It might need to create a session first which i'm hazy on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

The solution to this was somewhat indirect.  We were not able to do a straight POST because the the page incremented the actual POST url in a way that was generally impossible to predict.

The solution that we used was installing Selenium web driver and using that to simulate the dropdown visible values and button clicks.

This worked out very cleanly.

Thanks and HTH anyone else who might have a similar problem.